# ts error when trying to get state via listener Api.getState() in createListenerMiddleware RTK

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I use TS + React + RTK in my project.
Trying to create a listener using createListenerMiddleware and access the state slice like this:

```
const array: number[] = [...listenerApi.getState()[NameSpace.Array].array];
```

And as a result I get an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhD8u.png)

I can't understand how to fix it. Help please

Answer (score 0):

You just need to type the api parameter of the effect as such `api: ListenerEffectAPI<IStorageState, any>`.

EDIT: this turned out to only be a partial solution.

The way to fix this is documented [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#typescript-usage).

```
// listenerMiddleware.ts
import { createListenerMiddleware, addListener } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { TypedStartListening, TypedAddListener } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

export type AppStartListening = TypedStartListening<RootState, AppDispatch>

export const startAppListening =
  listenerMiddleware.startListening as AppStartListening

export const addAppListener = addListener as TypedAddListener<
  RootState,
  AppDispatch
>
```